# Are eigenvalues in quantum mechanics related to eigenfunctions (in the PDE sense) or to linear algebra and eigenvectors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematics, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, differential-equations

I'm in 10th grade and a beginner in the amazing world of quantum physics, I want to become a mathematician but I like quantum mechanics as well. The eigenvalues in Schrödinger wave equation used to describe the motion on electrons and other fundamental particles. Are they mathematically related to the solutions of partial differential equations (eigenfunctions) or to the eigenvalues of a square matrix (eigenvectors and eigenvalues)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both. There's essentially no difference at all between those two settings, when seen from the perspective of abstract linear algebra: in both, you have some [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) $V$ and some linear operator $\mathcal L:V\to V$, and you look for members $v\in V$ of the vector space which obey a property of the form
$$
\mathcal Lv=\lambda v,
\tag 1
$$
where $\lambda$ is known as the eigenvalue. The vector $v$ is normally known as an eigenvector, but it may also be appropriate to use the terms eigenstate or eigenfunction ─ which are nevertheless completely synonymous with eigenvector. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then the eigenvalue equation $(1)$ can be phrased in terms of square matrices and row vectors, but if $\mathcal L$ is some differential operator (as in the PDE form of the time-independent Schrödinger equation) then that is no longer possible, but that fact does not detract in any way from the abstract properties of the eigenvalue relation.

Comment: The vector $v$ in the definition above should be non-zero (if else $0$ would be an eigenvector of any linear operator  for any $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, thus making the notions of resolvent set and spectrum essentially useless). It is also probably worth to point out that, for (bounded) operators on an infinite dimensional (Banach) space (the ones you are considering), the notions of resolvent and spectrum are the ones that should really be looked at, since the set of eigenvectors may often be empty, or not describing with sufficient accuracy the whole operator.

Comment: @yuggib Those are boring technicalities that are *far*, far out of scope on a thread where OP is in 10th grade.

Comment: These are just "boring technicalities" in your opinion, that may however differ from the one of others (like mine). In addition, an answer on this site should be useful not only for the OP, but also to other users. So even if the answer should take in some account the eventual background of the OP, it should also at least contain the least number of inaccuracies.

Comment: And your answer contains some inaccuracies not unrelated to my "boring" comment above. For example, the "PDE form" of which Schrödinger equation? The one for the evolution of a particle in some potential $V$? or the (horribly) so-called "time-independent" Schrödinger equation? The first is not an eigenvalue equation, and the second fails to describe the physical behavior of a free (or in general non-trapped) particle, since it has *no solution* in $L^2$ (the Laplacian operator has purely continuous spectrum).

Comment: @yuggib You're welcome to add your own answer if you consider it necessary. For now, I'll thank you if you stop adding comments that are actively confusing to the OP under mine.

Comment: I am done with single var calculus and most of linear algebra I have just recently started with multivariable calc. So I have a rough idea on what Emilio Pisanty was talking about however since since in yuggibs comment the mathematical terms are only coming in $v$ form I'm not quite sure what to make of it.

Comment: @user167920 Frankly, you can disregard all of yuggib's comments at this stage. They are important technicalities but they remain technicalities and they would only stand in the way of the essential core structures that you should be focusing on at this point. You will have plenty of time for Banach spaces, resolvents and spectra when you get to them, at the appropriate time.

Comment: @user167920 The one take-home message from all this mathematical arguing is that in a first linear algebra course, you study vector spaces with a *finite* number of dimensions (often 2 or 3, corresponding to the Euclidean view of "real world" 2D or 3D space) and therefore you can use matrix notation for calculations. However vector spaces involving *functions* have an *infinite* number of dimensions (in almost all situations), which brings in some more mathematical complications, and means that matrix notation is not very useful.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you for your guidance I am really a Padawan right now.

Comment: @alephzero thank you for your answer and yes I only understand matrices and linear transformations in 2 and 3 dimensions. Speaking of the infinite and looking at your username I have a question about the cardinality of sets containing infinite elements. I will probably ask it on the mathematics stack exchange.